# Trouble Fetching Value in Variable

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Basically here's my code which I'm having trouble with. Insanely new to mongoDB and would love to understand how to get values out of a JSON string that is returns in the variable 'line'.

```
public string get_data()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("metacorp");
            var cursor = collection.Find("{'movie_name' : 'Hemin'}").ToCursor();
            var line = "";
            foreach (var document in cursor.ToEnumerable())
            {
                using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                using (var jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(stringWriter))
                {
                    var context = BsonSerializationContext.CreateRoot(jsonWriter);
                    collection.DocumentSerializer.Serialize(context, document);
                    line = stringWriter.ToString();

                }
            }
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var d = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(line);
            var a  = d["movie_name"];
            return line;
        }
```

This is the output I get if I return line:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("58746dcafead398e4d7233f5"), "movie_name" : "Hemin"
>   }

I want to be able to fetch the value 'Hemin' into 'a'.

Comment: Seems that your example already gets the *movie_name*. Isn't that working?

Comment: @botond.botos, yes it does. I want to be able to store the value in the variable 'a'.

Comment: Do you have corresponding c# classes (e.g MetaCorp) etc. IMO it makes all the querying much easier if you can piggyback on the type system and Linq. Otherwise your code will be bloated with magic strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not what you're asking for but since you're using the c# driver then I would recommend the following. Assumes you have a c# class corresponding to metacorp collection or at least a serializer that handles it. Hope it helps.

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<MetaCorp>("metacorp");
var m = collection.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Movie_Name == "Hemin"); // Assuming 0 or 1 with that name. Use Where otherwise
var movieName = "Not found";
if(m!= null)
   movieName = m.Movie_Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have your dto class for movie ans just fetch the data from collection:

```
public class Movie
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string movie_name { get; set;}
}
```

...

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("metacorp");

var movies = collection.Find(x=>x.movie_name == "Hemin").ToEnumerable();
```